# #MYSQL facing error 1136 column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the below query through a java program.

```
mysql> INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_DETAILS
 (txn_id,txnd_stocksymbol,price,qty) values('1000400058','TFSCU','10.27','10');
```

> ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

However, I am facing **error 1136**.

I have the same count of fields and values.

My table description is :

```
mysql> desc transaction_details;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| txn_id           | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| txnd_stocksymbol | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| price            | decimal(7,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| qty              | int(10)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Please suggest what I am missing.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around numeric values.

Comment: I tried running this - I still get the same error -
`
---------------------INSERT INTO TRANSACTION_DETAILS values(10004000,'TFSCU',10.27,10); `
---------------------
ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: Can you create an sqlfiddle?

Comment: can you see if you can access this : 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c997

Comment: Yes i can access this. And it works without any error.

Comment: I am able to insert it there.. hmm..

Comment: Maybe a problem with the decimal separator.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. let me work on it.. I'll post how it gets fixed..

Comment: I dropped the table and created the table and inserted data again through a script. It's working now. 
Unclear why it did not work before... but I have removed the single quotes around the numeric values like you suggested.

Comment: Thank you Jens.. I investigated and found that there was a genuine 1136 error on an `after insert` trigger that is attached to the transaction_details table. 
1136 - the no of values provided should match the no of columns being inserted into.